# Best way to reset all security/ownership for NTFS?

Tags: windows, security, permissions, ntfs

How can I completely reset the security and ownership for a drive (ie. all subdirectories and files)?

I'm recreating a large RAID array and I'd like to "start fresh" with the absolute default security and permissions for everything.

I believe I need to run:

icacls *.* /reset /T /Q

EDIT: Also, what other files should I cleanup?  (ie. thumbs.db, the system .ntfs folder, etc?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Format the drive. That guarantees default security descriptors and cleans up everything else, too.

Update after comment from SofaKng:

Once you have created a fresh new volume copy everything back from your backup. Remember that permissions are not copied across volumes.

Comment: The problem is that I've backed up the data to another NTFS drive.  This will keep the ACLs, right?  Once I copy the data back to the new drive it will still have the same ACLs (which I don't want).

Comment: @SofaKng: `xcopy` or `robocopy` will not copy ACLs unless you specifically tell it to.

Comment: @SofaKng: Permissions are not retained when you copy to a different volume. See this KB: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310316