# Reset Security on Win7 Windows folder

Tags: security, windows-7, directory

Is there a way to reset the security settings on the c:\windows folder of Win7. I have found this approach [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/264258/best-way-to-reset-all-security-ownership-for-ntfs), but formatting an copying back seems a little complex.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the [subinacl.msi](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=e8ba3e56-d8fe-4a91-93cf-ed6985e3927b&displaylang=en#AffinityDownloads)-tool. Install it in your `System32`-folder.

After that, run these commands in 'Run'

```
subinacl /subdirectories %WINDIR% /sgrant=administrators=f 
subinacl /subdirectories %WINDIR% /sgrant=system=f
```

(They may take a while, so have patience)

Comment: Does this completely reset the permissions to default? Seems like this only adds administrators and system as full-permission-user. What if I want to reset the whole security back to default (including removal of user-permissions that are not default)?

Comment: Sgrant will add a Successfull (Allow) Audit Ace for the user and remove all existing Audit Ace for this user(or group). (Editted my post)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint. The installation and running the commands above works fine. But I am not sure, is this a full reset.

E.g. to overcome some issues I have changed the ownership (of c:\windows) to my user account, but it remains this way. A full reset should set this back to TrustedInstaller. I am no professional admin, but it looks not like afull reset to my. Am I wrong?

Comment: That's what I meant. A solution to reset permissions to pure default-permissions would be cool.

Comment: Administrator & System are the defaults for the windows-installation dir. There is no 'restore-to-default-button' so this is the only way I know off.

Comment: Please do not get it wrong, your approach is working and so far the only (and hence best) solution. Only it is not a full reset IMHO. I have a similar issue pending at MS support, see what they come up with. I'll let you know - TiZon I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I believe TiZon is right, there is no way to restore the permissions on Vista or later, take a look at this article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313222.

Comment: @Horst Walter no offense taken :-). I just wouldn't know what to do otherwise :-).

Comment: Yep, Microsoft support came back withe exactly that KB article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313222

Thanks to all helping me on this.